# Maven parent.relativePath of POM SNAPSHOT points at new parent instead of old parent error

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven

I have trouble building in eclipse where subprojects' main artifact is not parent but another pom.xml file.

Real problem lies is old pom.xml file artifact children are referring are actually in the folder structure, but maven tries to download it from repository.

This is a local pom.xml file and corresponds to old build of the project.

Anyway to solve this problem?

```
[DEBUG] Using local repository at C:\Users\user\.m2\repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\user\.m2\repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata com.company:oldparent:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\user\.m2\repository)
[DEBUG] Failure to find com.company:oldparent:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of spark-package has elapsed or updates are forced
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata com.company:oldparent:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\user\.m2\repository)
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.company:projname:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.company:sparkapps:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.company:utils:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.company:oozie:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[WARNING] 'parent.relativePath' of POM com.company:feature1:1.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\user\Desktop\PROJ_GIT\main_path\sub_path\sparkapps\feature1\pom.xml) points at com.company:sparkapps instead of com.company:oldparent, please verify your project structure @ line 11, column 13
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.company:feature1:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.company:oldparent:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT in https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of spark-package has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 11, column 13
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: com.holdenkarau:spark-testing-base_2.11:jar -> duplicate declaration of version (?) @ line 107, column 21
[WARNING] 'parent.relativePath' of POM com.company:feature3:1.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\user\Desktop\PROJ_GIT\main_path\sub_path\sparkapps\feature2\pom.xml) points at com.company:sparkapps instead of com.company:oldparent, please verify your project structure @ line 11, column 13
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.company:feature3:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.company:oldparent:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT in https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of spark-package has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 11, column 13
[
```

[image: actual pom file of old build exists]

Answer (score 0):

Found solution with help from collegue:
The problem here was you first need to "maven install" modules required first and that have to be in order.
Once those snapshots are compiled then you can compile the next module.